# How to fit tabular report with > 30 columns fit onto a single print page

Tags: layout, design, reports, printing

Please excuse my English and nay grammatical errors you observe.

I am trying to create a report in SSRS, the data-set contains more than 30 columns. The issue is that all columns don't fit onto a single page and spills out on the next page.

As this is a financial report, every column is important. Readability is also one concern here.

Also i have tried going landscape and using a larger page size (A3 and A2). This works perfectly for exporting reports to PDF but printing is another issue to be dealt with. The only printer/pages available here for reporting are of size A4.

To summarize: Need to fit > 30 columns for a report in a single page with focus on readability, exportability and fitting the print on an A4 page size.

Any help related to design ideas or pointers where i should look would be appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really an UX question that can be answered through expertise or research this site usually deals with.

Comment: It is mostly a UI problem, not experience problem. So, check graphic design section too. Although, keeping the question open is not a bad idea, as someone else might be able to provide suggestions. 

On that note, if it is possible, you can divide the columns to two rows. Obviously, it will still affect the readability if you are not used to see the data in that style.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying that if it won't fit on a single sheet, it's probably best not to force it onto a single sheet as doing so will always negatively affect readability, especially on something as data heavy as a financial report. Be sure to carefully weigh up the benefit of having it on a single page with the decreased readability.

However, let's assume that you truly have to have it on a single page.

The obvious thing to do would be to decrease the font size. If doing this, I would ensure that you're using a sans-serif font as the serifs can [impede the readability of characters at very small sizes](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-1/type-anatomy/serif-vs-sans-for-text-in-print). Because it's numerical data, use a monospaced font to ensure the numbers line up. [This post from the Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9246/what-are-great-fonts-for-information-heavy-data-tables) seems to suggest Consolas as suitable candidate.

If it's just the column labels which are taking up the width, rotating the labels 90 degrees so the text runs vertically might be a solution. Or even better, make them run at 45 degrees so your reader doesn't have to tilt their head quite so much:

[image]

But again, it's unsafe to assume that because it's readable to you, it will be readable to everyone. And especially with numerical data, I doubt that people will want to spend extended periods of time squinting at it, or trying desperately to find a particular value in a dense sea of values.

You might also have luck asking this on the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) as they'll have particular expertise in print. I think this question is on the fringes of the UX Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Few guidelines for such reports:

- Use minimum page margins on all sides.
- Use minimum body margins on all sides.
- Use Minimum padding in the display text box.
- Use the best font for smallest yet clearest view. i.e. **Tahoma**

Good luck.